# mySQL - Group date field into weeks and sum data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently looking to group some dates into their respective weeks while summing up a field for each week (in this case it is 'distance'). On top of this, I want to provide a date range for the query to be made on. So for I have the following SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT week(lapDate) AS WEEK, sum(distance) AS DISTANCE
        FROM activity
        LEFT JOIN lap
        ON activity.activityID = lap.lapDate
        AND activity.email = '$email'
        AND lap.lapDate BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'
        GROUP BY WEEK
        ";
```

No errors are occurring, I'm just having null values returned. Any suggestions?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: probably there is no data matching the condition. It would be good if you provide data and tables in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Without fully defining the columns (or providing proper DDLs) this kind of question is always frustrating to answer

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the date in the second table of a `left outer join`.  When there are no matches, then you are getting `NULL` values.

```
SELECT week(a.activityID) AS WEEK, sum(distance) AS DISTANCE
FROM activity a LEFT JOIN
     lap
     ON a.activityID = lap.lapDate AND
        a.email = '$email' AND
        lap.lapDate BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'
GROUP BY WEEK;
```

It seems very strange to me that a column called `ActivityId` in one table would match a field called "date" in another.  Perhaps you have the wrong join criteria as well.

Comment: It does seem strange, but I assure this is valid. Both are date formatted and will definitely match.